# How can I display 2 charts side by side in react using material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-chartjs, formsy-material-ui

I am trying to display 2 charts side by side at the centre of the page but I'm unable to do so. I am relatively new to material UI.

```
<Grid container spacing={2} >
<Grid item sm={6}  > 
<Nifty50/>
</Grid>

<Grid item sm={6}  > 
<Sensex/>
</Grid>
</Grid>
```

It ends up looking like this. [image: like this]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your charts are of fixed width. where as the `Grid Container` and `Grid Item` is  fullwidth/fluid. hence `Grid Item` have more size. than the charts. and by default contents inside the `Grid Item` are left aligned.

you can add the `Box` with `text-align="center"` for your charts. this is one way of centering the content.

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  <Grid item sm={6}> 
    <Box textAlign="center">
      <Nifty50/>
    </Box>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item sm={6}> 
    <Box textAlign="center">
     <Sensex/>
    </Box>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```